# XPath get parent element

Tags: xml, xpath

I have an XPath related question. I have a list of XML entries like this:

```
<NavigationEntry>
<BaseData>
    <Name>Entry Name</Name>
  </BaseData>
  <Relation>
    <RelationEntry isDefault="0">
      <ParentNavigationEntry>456</ParentNavigationEntry>
      <Order>200</Order>
    </RelationEntry>
  </Relation>

<NavigationEntry>
  <BaseData>
    <Name>Entry Name</Name>
  </BaseData>
  <Relation>
    <RelationEntry isDefault="0">
      <ParentNavigationEntry>123</ParentNavigationEntry>
      <Order>200</Order>
    </RelationEntry>
  </Relation>
```

The question is: how do I get all navigation entries that has a Field ParentNavigationEntry with the value 456.

I tried 
`//NavigationEntry//RelationEntry[ParentNavigationEntry="456"]`

But this only gives me the RelationEntry Field, but I need the NavigationEntry Field.

Is it possible to solve this with a single XPath query?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The question is: how do I get all
>   navigation entries that has a Field
>   ParentNavigationEntry with the value
>   456.

```
//NavigationEntry[
   /Relation
      /RelationEntry
         /ParentNavigationEntry = 456
]
```

**Note:** Select those `NavigationEntry` elements and then filter predicate. Also, when the schema is well known it's not good practice to use `//` because it traverse the whole descendant tree even after a match.

Comment: You did not use quotations around 456. When is that allowed? I have xpath in similar structure but only works when quoted.

Answer (score 0):

Add /ParentNavigationEntry to your XPath..

Example...

```
//NavigationEntry//RelationEntry[ParentNavigationEntry="456"]//ParentNavigationEntry
```