# conditional xpath? need xpath if more specific xpath is matched

Tags: python, xpath

I'm trying to create a list of dicts with two data items.

The page I'm looking at has 37 matches for `//div[@id='content']/*[self::p or self::h2]/a[2]`; however, it only has 33 matches for 
`//div[@id='content']/*[self::p or self::h2]/a[contains(@href,'game')]/img[@src]`
The two xpaths have `//div[@id='content']/*[self::p or self::h2]` in common. I effectively only want to get the element matched for the first xpath if the second xpath is matched, and leave the 4 without the second element behind.

I'm hoping that this can be accomplished with xpath but if not, could use some advice on writing a function that achieves this in python.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the matching in XPath, and then simply take the resulting nodes parent in Python.

Comment: Thanks. It looks like this is what I am trying to here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5597538/xpath-get-parent-element

Comment: However, I don't understand how to apply it. Can someone point me towards a reference for this that is more clear.

Comment: I don't know what you mean with "apply it".

Comment: I think will be clear. If I was working with this xpath examples page http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_examples.asp I would be trying to get the book category when the price = $30.            <book category="COOKING">
  <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
  <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
  <year>2005</year>
  <price>30.00</price>
</book>

Comment: @user1780952: The XPath for that example on W3Schools for your question would be: /bookstore/book[price = 30]/@category

Comment: @user1780952: I know what you want. I don't understand what your question is.

Comment: After looking more closely at the html, I don't think this can be handled with an xpath because the elements I want don't share a parent.

Comment: @user1780952: Then it's not HTML, where they all share a parent: <HTML>.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like this is what you want:

```
//div[@id='content']/*[self::p or self::h2]/a[2][contains(@href,'game') and img[@src]]
```

Could you give that a try?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know what you mean by "The second XPath is a[1]". Could you clarify that? Are you saying that you want to find a certain `a[2]` whose previous neighbor has an image under it?  If so, that is not at all clear from your question.

Comment: Sorry I am having a hard time explaining this. What I believe the "parent" is would be "//div[@id='content']/*[self::p or self::h2]". There are 37 matches where the xpath extends with "/a[2]" and 33 matches where the xpath extends with "/a[contains(@href,'game')]/img[@src]". So where I find instances of the latter, I want that value, but I also I want the matches for ""/a[2]" which are part of the same record. Let me know if this is more clear, I probably could explain better if I knew the terminology better.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this XPath:

```
//div[@id='content']/*[self::p/a[contains(@href,'game')]/img[@src] or self::h2/a[contains(@href,'game')]/img[@src]]/a[2]
```